# Цикл с постусловием

Tags: c++builder

Дана такая задача.

> Программа «задумывает» число в диапазоне от 1 до 10 и предлагает пользователю угадать число из 5 попыток.

Программа:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Rus(const char *text);

{
    srand(time(0));

    int a;                        // задуманное число
    int b;                        // число которое вводит пользователь
    int c = 5;                    // число попыток
    a = rand() % 10;
    do {
        c--;
        cout << Rus(" Введите число: ");
        cin >> b;
    }
    while (c != 0 || b != a)
    if (c == 0 && b != a)
        cout << Rus(" у вас не осталось попытки, вы проиграли ");
    else if (a == b)
        cout << Rus(" вы победили ");
    getch();
    }
    char bufRus[256];
    char *Rus(const char *text) {
        CharToOem(text, bufRus);
        return bufRus;
    }
}
```

Но программа выдает ошибки. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: и что за ошибки выдает программа ? У Вас не хваает ";" после *while*. А что у Вас делает функция *srand* до обьявления переменных ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в условии на цикл: нужно, чтобы оба условия выполнялись (вместо оператора "или", нужен оператор "и" &&).  У меня не работает функция Rus, поэтому переписал с латиницей.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int a;                       
    int b;                        
    int c = 5;                    
    a = rand() % 10;

    do 
    {
        c--;
        cout << "Vvedi chislo: ";
        cin >> b;
    }
    while ((c != 0) && (b != a));

    if (c == 0 && b != a)
        cout << "Game over!";
    else if (a == b)
        cout << "Vi pobedili.";

    getch();
}
```

Код правил при помощи компилятора Dev C++.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Я все понял.